# Container of Web Client in JEE

Tags: java-ee-7

As far as I understood, client tier components are running on the client machine and within their respective [container](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview004.htm#BNABO). From JEE-7 specification, there are three types of [JEE Client Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview003.htm#BNABB), the  Web Client,  Application Client and Applet.

It is clear that the container of the *Applet* is "Applet Container", and the container of *Application Client* is "Application Client Container (ACC)".
My question is that what is the container for the *Web Client*? The "ACC"? or the "Web Container". It is confusing because one may think "Web Container" is a container only for the Web-Tier Components and not the Client-Tier Components.

Answer (score 0):

Understand your concerns, I found this doc a bit confusing also.

The **Container** in this docs is referred to some managed environment, which provides common pieces of functionality and allow your code/components to run there.

Therefore Container for **Web Client** (HTML/JS generated by Web Components) will be the **Web Browser itself**, as it manages the lifecycle of your JS code/provides general APIs/etc.

You are right, in terms of EE spec **Web Container** is the Container for Web Tier's Components, not Client Tier's.